# How to send a template from desktop to mobile device without loosing css

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I am sending a email from desktop/laptop to mobile devices, but it loosing css like line alignments spaces and text is coming horizontal.

so please tell me what css I must have to use for android and ios mobiles,

i am using this CSS but not working...

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 566px) {
    .campaign_tem {
        width: 80% !important;
    }
    .table_align {display:none !important;width:100%;color:red;}
} `
```

Comment: Do you have the meta tag to indicate that your site is mobile capable ? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Are you trying to style a webpage or an email on mobile devices?

Comment: I am trying to give a style to gmail text template which is written in html5 to send all devices...

Comment: Is the css in your page or in an external folder?

Comment: A lot of email clients ignore styling.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this not too long ago, but gmail only accepts inline-styling so nothing in the header.